# Program works from Eclipse but not from executable JAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

Below is my code which works perfect in Eclipse Java Project

```
    String IEPath = "src/IEDriverServer.exe";
    File file = new File(IEPath);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",file.getPath());
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

If I export the same code to a runnable JAR file and double click it or if I run it from command prompt gives below exception

```
    The driver ececutable does not exist C:\Backup\New folder\src\IEDriverServer.exe
```

I have copied IE exe inside my Java Project and have exported the Java Project including the IE exe. When I run the JAR, it is failing to pick the IE exe path.
Please help! TIA!

Comment: Objects in a jar are not files and you can't use `File` to access them.

Comment: @greg-449 Many thanks for your comment. Could you please help me what code I should right so that it reads my IE exe path. TIA!

Comment: @ShawnDsouza use class.getResource("path to exe relative to this class")

Comment: I got answer to my question on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

1. Read the resource inside the jar. See more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar).
2. Use [WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/)to automate the management of `IEDriverServer.exe`.

For alternative 2, simply import the WebDriverManager library in your project and change your code:

```
String IEPath = "src/IEDriverServer.exe";
File file = new File(IEPath);
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",file.getPath());
```

... by:

```
InternetExplorerDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
```

Comment: Thanks all for your precious comments.

Comment: I got answer to my question on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615441/how-to-access-resource-files-from-jar-file?noredirect=1&lq=1